# Symfony 2 Doctrine one-to-many not writing join table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I am trying to create a one-to-many between `tax_rates` and `countries`, where one tax rate can have multiple countries associated with it, with a join table on the countries referencing the tax_rate with the following schema:

```
/** @Entity **/
class TaxRates
{
    ...

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Country", mappedBy="tax_rate", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    protected $country;

    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->country = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity **/
class Country
{
    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\TaxBundle\Entity\TaxRates", inversedBy="country")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="taxrate_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    protected $tax_rate;
}
```

I have the following in my Symfony form from the TaxRates with the country being included as a Entity Type:

```
$builder->add('country', 'entity', array(
                'class' => "AcmeDemoBundle:Country",
                'property' => "name",
                "multiple" => true,
            ))
```

When I load into the form, enter valid data and then submit it, it writes correctly into the TaxRates table. However it does not add the id into the join table on the countries so I have a record, with nothing referencing it.

If anyone could advise on what I'm doing wrong that'd be fantastic, thank you.

Comment: why do you have a join table ? Your country entity is many to one. Which that a Tax_rate can be associated to one or many countries. If a country can have one or more tax_rates, you need a many-to-many relation.

Comment: @Hakim I am using the join table as stated in the doctrine documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional - its one tax_rate to many countries, it cannot be on a many-to-many

Comment: a country cannot be associated to different tax_rates?

Comment: @Hakim For example if you are shipping goods from the UK to any country in the EU you have to charge at 20% - So there will be multiple countries to one rate.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand very well. In your example, I understand that when you submit your form you insert a row in tax_rate, and one or multiples rows in country. and each row in country should have the tax_rate_id right? and your problem is that country rows have a tax_rate_id set to null ?

Comment: @Hakim Yes, basically when the form is submitted it creates a tax_rate record and then it should get the id of that record and in the countries table add all of the associated countries with that id into the joincolumn (taxrate_id) - Sorry if it's a little confusing.

Comment: No I finally got it, but I'm sorry I don't see what's wrong, Cerad answer was a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess but I suspect you are not calling $country->setTaxRate.  Do something like:

```
class TaxRates {
  function addCountry($country) {
    $this->countries[] = $country;
    $country->setTaxRate($this); // This is what might be missing
```

Comment: We did this, and this is how we do it for any other association, however on the above example I added a var_dump();exit; into this function and it didn't trigger - So my only thought is that it did not call this function entirely.

Comment: Ok.  I'll delete the answer as it was just a guess.  Hmmm.  You do have some @Entitys instead of @ORM/Entity in your posted code.  Copy/paste error?  Maybe you have some old mapping files under AcmeDemoBundle\Resources\config\doctrine?  If so then your annotations are being ignored.

Comment: The /** @Entity **/ and all of the Acme/Demo etc etc... is just a placeholder so that the filepaths are kept private as it contains companies names etc. All the filepaths join and are correct and it is valid code.

Comment: Far enough.  As long as you are certain that your actual code uses @ORM\Entity instead of @Entity then I am out of ideas.

Comment: So are we, we could handle the request explicitly through the controller and manually hardcode into it to work - but surely this should fundamentally work through Doctrine? - thanks anyway for having a look.

Comment: " manually hardcode" is a bit alarming.  I suppose you could update your question with your controller action code.  I assume you are following the usual pattern and not doing anything strange?  And the country table is your so called "join table"?  You only have two tables right?